# Having a <button> tag completely over a <div> element

Tags: html, css, button, position

I have tried to make a  tag that completely covers a div element and when clicked, the button element would disappear. 
HTML:

I have tried setting height and width to 100%, but this does not fill the  area entirely... how do I fix this?

```css
#startstorybutton {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.5vw;
  right: 20vw;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  color: white;
  Font-size: 50px;
  font-style: italic;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  cursor: url(cursors/select.PNG), pointer;
}

#story {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Three_little_pigs_%28geograph_4633727%29.jpg/1200px-Three_little_pigs_%28geograph_4633727%29.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="story">
  <div>
    <p id="storytitle">The Three Little Pigs</p>

    <div>
      <p id="storybox"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="storybuttonsection">
      <button type="button" id="backbutton"><span>Go back</span></button>
      <p id="pagenumber">121212</p><button id="continuebutton"><span>Continue</span></button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <button type="button" id="startstorybutton">Start the story!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sounds like an X/Y problem. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I want to have a button that covers an area full of text, so that when a user would like to continue he would press the button, the button would disappear and then they would see the text

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you to show the issue - the visibility hidden does not help

Comment: Sorry, im new to this website, what do i change in the snippet and how do i use it?

Comment: Oh yep i done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to position the button element on top of the "hidden element", if you set the main element position to relative you can then position the child element absolute over it (`top: 0; right: 0`) with the height and width to 100%.

For hide the button, the easy way is to add a listener event to the button and then hide it (or remove it) with javascript.

```css
#startstorybutton {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  color: white;
  Font-size: 50px;
  font-style: italic;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  cursor: url(cursors/select.PNG), pointer;
}

#story {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Three_little_pigs_%28geograph_4633727%29.jpg/1200px-Three_little_pigs_%28geograph_4633727%29.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="story">
  <div>
    <p id="storytitle">The Three Little Pigs</p>

    <div>
      <p id="storybox"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="storybuttonsection">
      <button type="button" id="backbutton"><span>Go back</span></button>
      <p id="pagenumber">121212</p><button id="continuebutton"><span>Continue</span></button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <button type="button" id="startstorybutton" onclick="this.style.display = 'none'">Start the story!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: When i used the code for #story that you have provided, the button instead fills the entire page... Im not sure what's wrong

Comment: Have you set `#story { position: relative; }`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure of your HTML structure. But as you described your problem I have created an example for you.

You need t make changes in your HTML to make it simple and straightforward.

The story div contains the button, which will be absolutely positioned to fit the entire div.

I have thrown in a small bit of jQuery to show how it will look like.

```js
$(function(){
  $("button.overlay").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.story{
 width: 250px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align:center;
 position: relative;
}

.overlay{
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="story">
 Here goes the story!
 <button class="overlay">read story button</button>
</div>
```